# Show time depending on timezone on wordpress with js and php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin that offer the user time_slots to be booked. The problem is that it doesnt matter where in the world you are you will see the hours in utc-4. I want client to see the time reflected by their timezone

im a huge js/php newb, but i guess i would need a small function that translate $slot to the user time before printing it with

```
while (strtotime($date_from) < strtotime($end_date)) 
         {
             $cdiv++;

             $day_num_of_week = date('N', strtotime($date_from));   


             ?>
              <h3><?php echo date('l, j F, Y', strtotime($date_from))?> - <?php echo  $day_num_of_week?></h3>

              ?>

              <div class="bup-time-slots-divisor" id="bup-time-sl-div-<?php echo $cdiv?>">

             <?php  //get available slots for this date

             $time_slots = $this->get_time_slot_public_for_staff($day_num_of_week,  $staff_id, $b_category, $time_format);


 $cdiv_range = 0 ;

 foreach($time_slots as $slot)
             {
                  $cdiv_range++;                 
                 ?>

                <li id="bup-time-slot-hour-range-<?php echo $cdiv?>-<?php echo $cdiv_range?>">

                <span class="bup-timeslot-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $slot['from'].' &ndash; '.$slot['to']?></span>
                <span class="bup-timeslot-count"><span class="spots-available">1 time slot available</span></span>
                <span class="bup-timeslot-people">
                <button class="new-appt bup-button bup-btn-book-app" bup-data-date="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_from))?>" bup-data-timeslot="<?php echo $b_category.'-'.$staff_id?>">

                <span class="button-timeslot"></span><span class="bup-button-text">
                <?php _e('Book Appointment','bookingup')?></span></button>
                 </span>

                </li>   

<?php  } //end for each time slots ?>

</div>


<?php 
 //increase date
 $date_from = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date_from)));


  } 

?>

</ul>
```

i want the user to see the timeslot depending on their timezone,
ej in australia its a day later, or in x city its 2h earlier

any help would be amazing!!

Comment: You can set time as time machine with javascript

Comment: Hey Conan, could you explain a bit more how one do that please

Comment: There is the answer tell me if something is not clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
```

and put the variable dateTime into the tag HTML that you want like this :

```
document.getElementById('idElement').innerHTML = dateTime;
```

and your tag HTML is like that :

```
 <div id='idElement'>Here you will find your input (time)</div>
```